# GSA search by meta tag and no query

Tags: google-search, google-search-appliance

I am currently trying to implement GSA for a site which has multiple collections for different "Sections" of the site. On the site the are area pages which will bring back all results in a collection with a meta tag filter applied with no keyword search.

E.g.

Area A will bring back Collection/Section A with filter of meta tag filter of department: accounts

Area B will bring back Collection/Section A with filter of meta tag filter of department: sales

Currently to achieve this I am trying to run this search query:

> /search?q=&output=xml_no_dtd&site=Articles_Collection&getfields=department.teasertext.publisheddate&partialfields=department:ACCOUNTS

This does bring back results but it doesn't bring back all results and some are items which matches this criteria isn't being brought back.

Does anyone know how I can implement this better or know why it brings back some of the results and not all?

Also, the results are not in the next page since it does not bring back enough results for it to have another result page (but should do when it brings back all the expected results)

Comment: Do you get the same results with inmeta syntax?

Comment: Yes i get the same result by using inmeta syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the solution to this and it turns out that the issue is with filtering.

For the site I am working with, many of the results come from the same directory and with GSA default and directory filtering, it will not bring back more than 2 results from the same directory.

So to fix this I have turned filtering off.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a query with inmeta:department=ACCOUNTS

q=inmeta:department%3DACCOUNTS

which based on your previous query would be:

search?q=inmeta:department%3DACCOUNTS&output=xml_no_dtd&site=Articles_Collection&getfields=department.teasertext.publisheddate

(which is what it would be in the browser)